# Is 一人10個 a colloquial form of １人あたり10個?

Tags: grammar

I came across the sentence

> 一人１０個りんごを与える

From what I can gather, it simply says "will give 10 apples to each person".

I've seen the grammar あたり and につき that is also used for this idea of "per x"/"apiece". Does the sentence still grammatically mean the same thing if you add in either あたり or につき after 一人?

> 一人あたり１０個りんごを与える

> 一人につき１０個りんごを与える

If so, is dropping あたり/につき here just a colloquial way to express the "10 apples per person" idea?

Comment: Interestingly, "一人10個" is exactly how you'd write "10 per person" in modern Chinese.

Comment: It's not particularly colloquial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, is dropping あたり/につき here just a colloquial way to express the "10 apples per person" idea?

Exactly!